# Delphi Android RESTRequest: channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed

Tags: android, rest, delphi, crash, firemonkey

After several times running `RESTRequest.Execute` without any errors, my `Android` application crashes randomly.

Although I'm developing with `Firemonkey`, I could only get to the error by checking it at Android Studio's DDMS logcat.

> 535-614/? E/InputDispatcher﹕ channel '221d0340 com.mycompany.myappname/com.embarcadero.firemonkey.FMXNativeActivity (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!

I found out that it usually indicates a **Memory Leak** in the application, however I'm clueless on how to prevent it from happening.

- *Debugging at Delphi shows no crashes at all.*

This is how I call the `RESTRequest`s on the main Form:

```
procedure TFormMain.ExecuteReadingThread(Sender: TObject);
begin

    aReadingThread := TThread.CreateAnonymousThread(
        procedure()
        begin

            try
                json_data_response_object := DM_KVA.GetDeviceData(communication_token, genset_id);
            except
                on E: Exception do
                begin
                    // Ignore
                end;
            end;

            TThread.Queue(aReadingThread,
            procedure()
            begin

            // Send UI Adjustments with a Thread-safe method

            end);


        end);

    // Default Threading Settings
    aReadingThread.FreeOnTerminate := true;
    aReadingThread.OnTerminate     := TerminateRead;
    aReadingThread.Start;

end;

procedure TFormMain.TerminateRead(Sender: TObject);
begin

        // Make Reading Thread take it's place
        ExecuteReadingThread(Sender);

end;
```

And this is how it's executed on the `DataModule`:

```
function TDM_KVA.GetDeviceData(ID_Token: string; ID_Device: string): TJSONObject;
var

    JSObj: TJSONObject;

begin

    // Set default RESTRequest parameters
    RESTRequest_KVA.Resource       := 'api/v1/TServerMethods1';
    RESTRequest_KVA.Method         := REST.Types.TRESTRequestMethod.rmGET;
    RESTRequest_KVA.ResourceSuffix := Format('DeviceData/%s', [ID_Device]);

    try
        // Execute command
        RESTRequest_KVA.Execute;

    except
        on E: EIdHTTPProtocolException do
        begin
            // Ignore
        end;
        on E: TRESTResponse.EJSONValueError do
        begin
            // Ignore
        end;
        on E: EIdUnknownProtocol do
        begin
            // Ignore
        end;

    end;

    // Verify response
    case (RESTResponse_KVA.StatusCode) of

        200:
        begin

            // Successful readz
            JSObj  := (RESTRequest_KVA.Response.JSONValue as TJSONObject);
            Result := JSObj;

        end;

    end;

end;
```

How can I avoid these random **Memory Leaks** from crashing my `Android` application?

Comment: `json_data_response_object` is never disposed of. Result of `GetDeviceData` can be undefined if StatusCode <> 200.

Comment: How exactly not setting `json_data_response_object`  free would lead to a memory leak?

Comment: N.B I know Android is managing objects with the ARC model, but since the scope of json_data_response_object is wider than ExecuteReadingThread, it will not be disposed of between calls, and hence the pointer will be overwritten and cause a memory leak.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the code is written, it seems as the scope of `json_data_response_object` is wider than `ExecuteReadingThread`.

Under ARC memory model an object is automatically disposed of when it goes out of scope. But here it does not go out of scope between calls to `ExecuteReadingThread`. Instead the pointer to the object is constantly overwritten until there are no memory left (lots of leaks).

> How can I avoid these random **Memory Leaks** from crashing my Android application?

There is no point in having a wide scope of the `json_data_response_object`, since accessing it outside the anonymous thread is dangerous (it is ok in the `OnTerminate` event handler though). I would recommend to *declare the object inside the anonymous thread*. Likewise the `aReadingThread` is better declared inside `ExecuteReadingThread` to avoid confusion.

---

One final point: Set the `Result` variable of `GetDeviceData` to nil at the beginning of the method to guarantee that a valid value is assigned in all circumstances.

Comment: Actually, there is no relation between the application crash and the `JSONObject`. I did learn a lot from reading your answer though. I'm still getting an application crash **only** executing the `RESTRequest` command. I tried to create and dispose the REST components, however it still crashes.

Comment: You could try using the [ExecuteAsync](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Berlin/en/REST.Client.TCustomRESTRequest.ExecuteAsync) function in order to reuse the request thread. Note also the comment: *iOS (and likely Android) will terminate an application if it considers the main thread to be unresponsive, i.e. if a running request takes more than a second or two to return. Sluggish behavior (caused by the main thread blocking) is considered to be unacceptable on mobile devices.*

Comment: I did try. It crashes the application as soon as the `rmGET` command is executed. Weirdly it doesn't happen with `rmPUT`, that works fine.